# How do I run a subsequent script if the text entry field is not focused?

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I am currently using the first script which is valid if I have my cursor selected in the text field.

```
tell application "System Events"
    
    tell application process "Capture One 20"
        set frontmost to true
        tell (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow")
            set subjElem to (first text field of scroll area 1 of group 2)
            set subjProp to properties of subjElem
            set subjFocused to focused of subjElem
            
    end tell
  end tell
end tell

return subjFocused
```

[image]

If I don't have my cursor in the text field than I get this error. How do I run a subsequent script based off this error?

[image]

```
tell application "Capture One 20"
    begin live view
end tell
```

Comment: Why not use try-catch so that when the UI element is not detected, you fall into the on error block and process your subsequent script?

Comment: @user3579815 Eventually I landed there, but I went with "if not exists" first, but then I realized the location would change between group 1 and group 2. Now I need to expand the scroll areas and groups. I will try using a wild card.